# Insert con varios registros con PDO PHP mediante un bucle

Tags: php, array, pdo, insert

Tengo esta función "add", que adiciona un código de producto 'X' en una tabla llamada "INVENTARIOS", me funciona bien, pero quiero agregar un fragmento de código en PHP que me inserte en una tabla llamada "PRECIOSXPROD" el código de producto por 'Y' veces según lista de precios se encuentren con la función 'mostrarListas', cuyo resultado almaceno en un arreglo $t_listas y lo recorro con un foreach, al hacer un echo de un índice me funciona bien, eso me indica que el arreglo obtiene los datos, pero al poner las líneas de código que en teoría deben hacer esa inserción, no obtengo nada en la tabla destino.

¿Estoy usando mal las sentencias o la sintaxis hay que corregirla en algún punto?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 17/04/18
La función inserta un solo registro con el número más alto registrado en la cantidad de listas de precios, es decir, si hay tres listas de precios registradas, solo inserta el código de producto en la última lista registrada (como si no hiciera inserción por cada iteración del foreach). Muchas gracias a @A. Cedano por la ayuda prestada.

```
static public function add($tabla, $datos) {


        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (ID_PRODUCTO, DESC_PROD, EXIST_MIN, DIAS_ENTREGA, ESQ_IMP, ID_LIN, SERVICIO, IMG_PRODUCTO, COSTO_PROM, COSTO_ULTIMO, EXIST) "
                . "VALUES (:ID_PRODUCTO, :DESC_PROD, :EXIST_MIN, :DIAS_ENTREGA, :ESQ_IMP, :ID_LIN, :SERVICIO, :IMG_PRODUCTO, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )");

        $stmt->bindParam(":ID_PRODUCTO", $datos["ID_PRODUCTO"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":DESC_PROD", $datos["DESC_PRODUCTO"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":EXIST_MIN", $datos["EXIST_MIN"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":DIAS_ENTREGA", $datos["DIAS_ENTREGA"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ESQ_IMP", $datos["ESQ_IMP"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ID_LIN", $datos["ID_LIN"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":SERVICIO", $datos["SERVICIO"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":IMG_PRODUCTO", $datos["IMG_PRODUCTO"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

       /*--
        * OBTENEMOS EL TOTAL DE LISTAS DE PRECIOS PARA PODER AGREGAR EL CÒDIGO POR CADA UNA
        * --*/ 

        $producto=$datos["ID_PRODUCTO"];
        $item = NULL;
        $valor = NULL;
        $t_listas= ControladorListaPrecios::mostrarListas($item, $valor);


        foreach ($t_listas as $key => $value) {
            //echo $producto.' '.$value["ID_LISTA"].'<br>'; /*HASTA ACÀ FUNCIONA, LO QUE NO FUNCIONA SON LAS SIGUIENTES $stmt2*/
            $stmt2= Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO PRECIOSXPROD (ID_PRODUCTO, ID_LISTA, PRECIO) "
                . "VALUES (:ID_PRODUCTO, :ID_LISTA, 0.0)");
            $stmt2->bindParam(":ID_PRODUCTO", $producto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt2->bindParam(":ID_LISTA", $value["ID_LISTA"], PDO::PARAM_INT);         
            $stmt2->execute();

        }

        /*HE AGREGADO EL !$stmt2 SUGERIDO EN ANTERIOR RESPUESTA PERO EN ESTA PARTE DEL CÓDIGO*/
        if ($stmt->execute() && !$stmt2->execute()) {
            return "ok";
        } else {
            return "error";
        }

        $stmt->close();
        $stmt = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué error estás teniendo? Puedes revisar el log de errores o bien poner este código así:  `foreach ($t_listas as $key => $value) { //echo $producto.' '.$value["ID_LISTA"].'<br>'; /*HASTA ACÀ FUNCIONA, LO QUE NO FUNCIONA SON LAS SIGUIENTES $stmt2*/
$stmt2= Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO PRECIOSXPROD (ID_PRODUCTO, ID_LISTA, PRECIO) "  . "VALUES (:ID_PRODUCTO, :ID_LISTA, 0.0)"); $stmt2->bindParam(":ID_PRODUCTO", $producto, PDO::PARAM_STR); $stmt2->bindParam(":ID_LISTA", $value["ID_LISTA"], PDO::PARAM_INT); if(!$stmt2->execute()){echo "Error: ". $stmt2->errorInfo()[2];}}`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta, fíjate que errores no me muestra, ya probé con erroInfo y errorCode, ahora bien, lo que está pasando es que en lugar de agregar de esta forma:

`**ID_PRODUCTO | ID_LISTA | PRECIO**
PROC001 - 1 - 0.0
PROC001 - 2 - 0.0
PROC001 - 3 - 0.0`
(en este caso hay 3 listas de precio)

Obtengo este resultado solamente
`**ID_PRODUCTO | ID_LISTA | PRECIO**
PROC001 - 3 - 0.0`

Pero cuando mando el echo de la variable VALUE["ID_LISTA"], me muestra el recorrido de las 3 listas guardadas.

Comment: Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/156345/edit)  explicando con mayor detalle la situación actual. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**18/04/18

CÓDIGO FUNCIONAL:

Al realizar algunos cambios, el código hace lo que busco, ahora bien, no sé si se la mejor práctica, pero lo pongo a continuación.

```
static public function add($tabla, $datos) {


        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (ID_PRODUCTO, DESC_PROD, EXIST_MIN, DIAS_ENTREGA, ESQ_IMP, ID_LIN, SERVICIO, IMG_PRODUCTO, COSTO_PROM, COSTO_ULTIMO, EXIST) "
                . "VALUES (:ID_PRODUCTO, :DESC_PROD, :EXIST_MIN, :DIAS_ENTREGA, :ESQ_IMP, :ID_LIN, :SERVICIO, :IMG_PRODUCTO, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )");

        $stmt->bindParam(":ID_PRODUCTO", $datos["ID_PRODUCTO"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":DESC_PROD", $datos["DESC_PRODUCTO"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":EXIST_MIN", $datos["EXIST_MIN"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":DIAS_ENTREGA", $datos["DIAS_ENTREGA"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ESQ_IMP", $datos["ESQ_IMP"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ID_LIN", $datos["ID_LIN"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":SERVICIO", $datos["SERVICIO"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":IMG_PRODUCTO", $datos["IMG_PRODUCTO"], PDO::PARAM_STR);




        if ($stmt->execute()) {

           /*--
            * OBTENEMOS EL TOTAL DE LISTAS DE PRECIOS PARA PODER AGREGAR EL CÒDIGO DE PRODUCTO NUEVO POR CADA UNA.
            * 
            * 18/04/18 AL PASAR ESTE CÓDIGO DENTRO DE ESTA CONDICIÓN FUNCIONÓ PARA AGREGAR
            * CADA CÓDIGO CREADO EN CADA LISTA DE PRECIOS--*/        


            $producto=$datos["ID_PRODUCTO"];
            $item = NULL;
            $valor = NULL;
            $t_listas= ControladorListaPrecios::mostrarListas($item, $valor);
            $contaListas= count($t_listas);

            $stmt2= Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO PRECIOSXPROD (ID_PRODUCTO, ID_LISTA, PRECIO) "
                    . "VALUES (:ID_PRODUCTO, :ID_LISTA, 0.0)");
            $stmt2->bindParam(":ID_PRODUCTO", $producto, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            /*AL USAR TAMBIÉN EL FOR CON LA CANTIDAD DE REGISTROS PARA REALIZAR LAS INSERCIONES, AL SER ENTERO EL CAMPO ID_LISTA,
              NO GENERÓ NINGÚN RESULTADO NO BUSCADO*/

            for($i=1;$i<=$contaListas;$i++) {                
                $stmt2->bindParam(":ID_LISTA", $i, PDO::PARAM_INT);         
                $stmt2->execute();
            }
            /*-------*/



            return "ok";
        } else {
            return "error";
        }

        $stmt->close();
        $stmt = NULL;
    }
```